Column too wide in table in a beamer: 'p' option and footnotesize don't help
I'm not sure, but the third column of a table I'm trying to create is too wide... I've tried using the 'p' option, or even footnotesize, but the column is still too big to show in beamer slide, and there's also too much useless space in it.
Here's my MWE:
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{AnnArbor}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
        \footnotesize
        \begin{tabular}{| c | c | c p{5cm} |}
                        \hline
                        \textbf{Operator} & \textbf{Description} & \textbf{Example} \\
                        \hline
                        \texttt{del dict[key]} & Delete the value associated with \texttt{key}. & \begin{lstlisting}[language=Python]
                my_dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
                del my_dict['a']  # my_dict is now {'b': 2}
                        \end{lstlisting} \\
                        \hline
                        \texttt{dict.keys()} & Return a view object of all keys. & \begin{lstlisting}[language=Python]
                my_dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
                keys = my_dict.keys()  # dict_keys(['a', 'b'])
                        \end{lstlisting} \\
                        \hline
                        \texttt{dict.values()} & Return a view object of all values. & \begin{lstlisting}[language=Python]
                my_dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
                values = my_dict.values()  # dict_values([1, 2])
                        \end{lstlisting} \\
                        \hline
                        \texttt{dict.items()} & Return a view object of all key-value pairs. & \begin{lstlisting}[language=Python]
                my_dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
                items = my_dict.items()  # dict_items([('a', 1), ('b', 2)])
                        \end{lstlisting} \\
                        \hline
                        \texttt{key in dict} & Check if \texttt{key} exists in the dictionary. & \begin{lstlisting}[language=Python]
                my_dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
                exists = 'a' in my_dict  # True
                        \end{lstlisting} \\
                        \hline
                        \texttt{dict.clear()} & Remove all items from the dictionary. & \begin{lstlisting}[language=Python]
                my_dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
                my_dict.clear()  # my_dict is now {}
                        \end{lstlisting} \\
                        \hline
                \end{tabular}
        % }
        \caption{Python Dictionary Operations}
        \label{tab:python_dict_operations}
\end{table}
    
\end{document}

Here's a screenshot of what I see:

How can I solve this?

you have made the 4th column a p but the third column is still c so single line as wide as the longest line

you can not have display environments like listing in a c column

And what also adds to spoiling the fun is that the blanks in front of the Python statements are considered part of the source code (which isn't unreasonable if you're programming Python)

You're missing a frame environment (use it with the fragile option to allow source code).

@DavidCarlisle thanks for your comments. Then, how can I put some multiple line code in a table, while making the table fit the slide?

@Anoldmaninthesea. Maybe have a look at https://texdoc.org/serve/booktabs.pdf/0 for some information how to design professional looking tables

Taking a step back, I don't know that the third column is really doing anything.  The code examples aren't all that different from the first column, and the comments just say "it did what I said it would".  Even worse, the dictionary view commands are really only useful in an iterating context, which you're not providing.

@Teepeemm you're right... I'll restructure it. ;)

To summarise the various comments in a community-wiki answer:

you shouldn't typeset anything in beamer without a frame environment (notice the incorrect vertical alignment and broken numbering). Use the fragile frame option to allow source code.
use a fixed-width column, e.g. p{...}, for the one which contains the listings
you will also save some space if you use a fixed-width column for the second column
don't indent code inside of lstlisting unless the indentation is part of the code (or use the gobble=... option to remove as many characters as needed)
allow line breaks in listsing: \lstset{breaklines}
adjust the above-/belowskip of listings to save some space
use a smaller font size or change the aspect ratio of your presentation if you need to squeeze so much information on a single slide. Alternatively, consider splitting it into two slides.


\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{AnnArbor}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{array}


\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize,
  breaklines
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{table}
\scriptsize
\lstset{
  aboveskip=-.7\baselineskip,
  belowskip=0pt
  }
\begin{tabular}{| l | >{\raggedright}p{2cm} | p{6.76cm} |}
\hline
\textbf{Operator} & \textbf{Description} & \textbf{Example} \\
\hline
\texttt{del dict[key]} & Delete the value associated with \texttt{key}. & \begin{lstlisting}[language=Python]
my_dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
del my_dict['a']  # my_dict is now {'b': 2}
\end{lstlisting} \\
\hline
\texttt{dict.keys()} & Return a view object of all keys. & \begin{lstlisting}[language=Python]
my_dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
keys = my_dict.keys()  # dict_keys(['a', 'b'])
\end{lstlisting} \\
\hline
\texttt{dict.values()} & Return a view object of all values. & \begin{lstlisting}[language=Python]
my_dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
values = my_dict.values()  # dict_values([1, 2])
\end{lstlisting} \\
\hline
\texttt{dict.items()} & Return a view object of all key-value pairs. & \begin{lstlisting}[language=Python]
my_dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
items = my_dict.items()  # dict_items([('a', 1), ('b', 2)])
\end{lstlisting} \\
\hline
\texttt{key in dict} & Check if \texttt{key} exists in the dictionary. & \begin{lstlisting}[language=Python]
my_dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
exists = 'a' in my_dict  # True
\end{lstlisting} \\
\hline
\texttt{dict.clear()} & Remove all items from the dictionary. & \begin{lstlisting}[language=Python]
my_dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
my_dict.clear()  # my_dict is now {}
\end{lstlisting} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
% }
\caption{Python Dictionary Operations}
\label{tab:python_dict_operations}
\end{table}
\end{frame}

\end{document}



Thanks samcarter ;)

@Anoldmaninthesea. You're welcome!
